# Using summed field in query twice with IIF statement - have I missed some syntax somewhere?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, iif

Having a bit of a problem with my code and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Essentially this query will return all employees for a given employer for a given year, along with the amount of their allowances, tax withheld, and gross payments they've received, and their Reportable Employer Superannuation Contributions (RESC).

RESC is any amounts (tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount) paid over and above the superannuation guarantee, which is gross payments (sum of tblPayment.GrossPayment) * super rate (tblSuperRate.SuperRate). Otherwise, RESC is 0.

The data that I currently have in my tables is as follows

```
SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment) = 1730
SUM(tblEmployee.TaxPayable) = 80
SUM(tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount) = 500
tblSuperRate.SuperRate = 9.5%
```

Therefore my query should be returning an amount of RESC of 500-(1730*9.5%)= 335.65.

However, my query is currently returning $835.65 - meaning that (1730*9.5%) is returning -335.65.

I can't figure out where my logic is going wrong - it's probably something simple but I can't see it. I suspect that it might be summing tblPayment.GrossPayment twice (edited on request)

```
SELECT 
tblEmployee.EmployeeID AS Id
SUM(tblPayment.Allowances) AS TotAllow, 
SUM(tblPayment.TaxPayable) AS TotTax, 
SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment) AS TotGross, 
(IIF 
((SUM(tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount)) <= (SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment)*tblSuperRate.SuperRate),
0,
(SUM(tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount) - (SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment)*tblSuperRate.SuperRate))
)) As TotRESC
FROM 
((tblEmployee 
LEFT JOIN tblPayment  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID = tblPayment.fk_EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN tblSuperPayments  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID = tblSuperPayments.fk_EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN tblSuperRate  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON (tblPayment.PaymentDate <= tblSuperRate.TaxYearEnd) // these two conditions might be returning 
AND (tblPayment.PaymentDate >= tblSuperRate.TaxYearStart) //two SuperRate rows because of using equals in both 
WHERE 
tblEmployee.fk_EmployerID = 1
GROUP BY 
tblEmployee.EmployeeID,
tblSuperRate.SuperRate;
```

Comment: You have `SUM(tblPayment.PaymentAmount) = 1730` but in your query you are summing the `GrossPayment` field of `tblPayment`.  Is one of these just a typo in your question, or is the problem that the `GrossPayment` field contains a negative amount that just happens to match the positive amount in the `PaymentAmount` field?

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It should be tblPayment.GrossPayment. Amending my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query I recommend you to just `group by` primary key (`EmployeeID`) of `tblEmployee` and the use the result as a sub query and do a join later tham using many columns of `tblEmployee`in group by which might cause duplicate rows.  I rewrote the query as I have mentioned above and added comments at places which might cause the error.

```
SELECT 
tblEmployee.TFN, 
tblEmployee.FirstName, 
tblEmployee.MiddleName, 
tblEmployee.LastName, 
tblEmployee.DOB, 
tblEmployee.MailingAddress, 
tblEmployee.AddressLine2, 
tblEmployee.City, 
tblEmployee.fk_StateProvinceID, 
tblEmployee.PostalCode, 
temp.TotAllow, 
temp.TotTax, 
temp.TotGross, 
temp.TotRESC
FROM
(SELECT 
tblEmployee.EmployeeID AS Id
SUM(tblPayment.Allowances) AS TotAllow, 
SUM(tblPayment.TaxPayable) AS TotTax, 
SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment) AS TotGross, 
(IIF 
((SUM(tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount)) <= (SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment)*tblSuperRate.SuperRate),
0,
(SUM(tblSuperPayments.PaymentAmount) - (SUM(tblPayment.GrossPayment)*tblSuperRate.SuperRate))
)) As TotRESC
FROM 
((tblEmployee 
LEFT JOIN tblPayment  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID = tblPayment.fk_EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN tblSuperPayments  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID = tblSuperPayments.fk_EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN tblSuperRate  // any reason for using left join over inner join
ON (tblPayment.PaymentDate <= tblSuperRate.TaxYearEnd) // these two conditions might be returning 
AND (tblPayment.PaymentDate >= tblSuperRate.TaxYearStart) //two SuperRate rows because of using equals in both 
WHERE 
tblEmployee.fk_EmployerID = 1
GROUP BY 
tblEmployee.EmployeeID,
tblSuperRate.SuperRate) temp // Does a single employee have more than one superrate why grouping by it?
JOIN tblEmployee ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID=temp.Id;
```

Comment: Srikanth,

Thanks for the reply!

I have tried your code however it gives me "syntax error in from clause" and highlights the last line where it says "join".

Comment: Did you see my comments? Can clarify those? I recommend you to first execute the sub query and see if gives any error and later execute the whole query

Comment: As for your comments I will answer them respectively:

My reasoning for left joins over inner joins is that an employee may not have super payments to them during the year; however they must have payments during the year for this query. So yes an inner join betweeen tblEmployee and tblPayment is appropriate. Hadn't picked up on that!

I'd rather not join SuperRate as I'd like for the user to be able to define the start and end date but I can't figure out how to have it in the FROM clause without it causing errors.

Comment: There is only one superrate per year; but yes, a single employee would have more than one superrate over many years. If we're restricting to a single year, they would only have one superrate.

Comment: Beat me to it; I tried to edit my comment but I took to long :)

Comment: `I'd rather not join SuperRate as I'd like for the user to be able to define the start and end date but I can't figure out how to have it in the FROM clause without it causing errors` Can expand on this? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: I have run the subquery (this is between the beginning of the FROM clause to "temp" on the second last line?) and I am still getting $835.65 as RESC.

Comment: Essentially this code will end up going in a VBA event; I am doing this all in SQL so I can get the code running first as debugging in VBA is a huge pain. 

The year start and end will be defined by a user through a combo box. Their selection will filter results to wage and super payments made between those two dates.

Obviously this will end up with additional statements in the WHERE clause i.e. (PaymentDate >= USERDEFINEDSTARTDATE AND <= USERDEFINEDENDDATE) but as my dataset does not have any payments outside this current year I have left them out for simplicity.

Comment: So sub query is running fine. The error was in the outer query. The problem you have is still in the sub query. Can you please update the question with just this query as it will make the code simple? and please the comments you mentioned above to the question too.

Comment: As tblSuperRate does not have any direct relationship to tblPayment or tblEmployee (it simply stores the superannuation guarantee rates for each particular year) but as I could not define it in the FROM clause without errors I have left joined it based on the payment dates.

One row of the tblSuperRate would be as per follows:

    TaxYearStart  TaxYearEnd  SuperRate
    01/07/2014    30/06/2014  9.5%

Comment: Why not store the Superrate in a variable and use it in where clause like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b4eb2dd6-1827-49e2-a2e7-e818400498b4/how-do-i-assign-the-result-of-select-query-to-a-variable-in-vba-for-msaccess?forum=accessdev)